# How can I convert my div to PNG without having to capture what is on screen?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, export, png

I have a solution which when my browser is open full screen at 100% zoom will capture a perfect png image of my .net timetable which is located within my div tag (omitting all other elements outside that div). The issue I have is when I zoom in to view a section of the timetable, or scroll down to view only the bottom of the timetable - in these instances when I then click my btnExport button the png image is captured as the zoomed in/chopped off timetable image which is viewable by the user on screen. Is there a way that I can grab my timetable image from within the div tag without chopping off part of the image according to what the user sees?

Below is my .Net code:

```
<div id="mydiv"  style="padding-bottom: 20px; background-color: white;" class="col-lg-10">
    <DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar ID="DayPilotUserTimetable" runat="server"
                            DataTextField="name"
                            DataIdField="id"
                            TimeFormat="Clock12Hours"
                            DataStartField="Start"
                            DataEndField="End"
                            HeaderDateFormat="D"
                            Days="7"
                            BusinessBeginsHour="8"
                            BusinessEndsHour="20"
                            HeightSpec="BusinessHoursNoScroll"
                            OnBeforeEventRender="DayPilotUserTimetable_BeforeEventRender">
    </DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar>
</div>

<div id="ImageFeatures" style="padding-top: 20px">
     <asp:HiddenField ID="imgHiddenField" runat="server" />
     <asp:Button ID="btnExport" Text="Download as Image" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="GenerateTimetableToImage" OnClientClick="return DownloadAsImage(this)" />
</div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DownloadAsImage(btnExport) {
        html2canvas($("#mydiv")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
            var mycanvas = canvas.toDataURL();
            $("[id*=imgHiddenField]").val(mycanvas);
            __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

And my C# code:

```
protected void GenerateTimetableToImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string canvas = Request.Form[imgHiddenField.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(canvas);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Timetable.png");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/ instead append you can do a post.

Comment: @AlisomMartins, that might work implementing across to a div on the same page but I can not see a way to use that example to display my full image in a **new window**, are you able to advise me on how to implement this for my solution I have provided?